# Append Query with Criteria not working

Tags: microsoft-access

I have an append query to calculate a total pricing and append to table.  The sum columns are working properly but the calculation column is not.  It gives the error that it is not part of an aggregate function.  I do not understand this error.  Below is my SQL:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Worksheet ( WEstProj, WItemInd, WItemName, WALHP, WAMP, WASubT, WEstimator, WItemType, WAIP )
SELECT DISTINCTROW tbl_ProjIndex.PItemProj, tbl_ProjIndex.PItem, tbl_ProjIndex.PItemName, Sum(tbl_SOW.STEHR) AS SumOfSTEHR, Sum(tbl_SOW.SCalMtlCst) AS SumOfSCalMtlCst, Sum(tbl_SOW.SCalSubCst) AS SumOfSCalSubCst, tbl_SOW.SEstIni, tbl_SOW.SItemType, [esPricingTotal] AS Expr1
FROM tblPSheet INNER JOIN ((tbl_ProjIndex INNER JOIN tbl_SOW ON tbl_ProjIndex.[ProjIdxID] = tbl_SOW.[ProjIdxID]) INNER JOIN tbl_Worksheet ON tbl_ProjIndex.ProjIdxID = tbl_Worksheet.ProjIdxID) ON tblPSheet.PricingID = tbl_Worksheet.ProjIdxID
GROUP BY tbl_ProjIndex.PItemProj, tbl_ProjIndex.PItem, tbl_ProjIndex.PItemName, tbl_SOW.SEstIni, tbl_SOW.SItemType
HAVING ((([esPricingTotal])=Round((((1+[tblPSheet]![PRABMU])*([tbl_SOW]![STEHR]*[tblPSheet]![PRHMPY])+([tbl_SOW]![SCalMtlCst]*[tblPSheet]![PRHMPY]=(1+"tblPSheet]![PRABMU]"+"tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU] "))+([tbl_SOW]![SCalSubCst])*(1+[tblPSheet]![PRABMU]+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU]))))));
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Your quesry does not include the specified expression[esPricingTotal])=Round((((1+[tblPSheet]![PRABMU])*([tbl_SOW]![STEHR]*[tblPSheet]![PRHMPY])+([tbl_SOW]![SCalMtlCst]*[tblPSheet]![PRHMPY]=(1+"tblPSheet]![PRABMU]"+"tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU] "))+([tbl_SOW]![SCalSubCst])*(1+[tblPSheet]![PRABMU]+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU])))))); as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: i THINK i HAVE FOUND PART OF THE ISSUE.   mY TABLE IS RELATED TO WHERE THE DATA IS GOING BUT NOT TO THE TABLE THAT HAS FIELDS i NEED TO USE.